# c# script is supposed to change text colour when hovering. Script isn't changing the colour in the game, but is changing the material colour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My c# script is supposed to change the colour of the text when the mouse is over a box collider. The colour does not visibly change in the game, but I can see the material changing in the bottom right. How can I make the colour change correctly?

I have made sure I have all of the necessary colliders but the material change isn't translating to the actual object.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseHover : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black; 
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red; 
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.black; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you are changing the color of the parent object, but the material you are looking at belongs to the child object. Maybe you need to reference your text color :)

Answer (score 0):

Well `GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color` will get the color of your material. You should maybe get the text component `GetComponent<Text>().color` :D

Comment: Also always cache components (= create a field you assign in Awake or Start and use that instead) when you can. Calling `GetComponent()` isnt exactly cheap - even if its probably not that big of a deal if you just do it on user input. But its a good habit.

Comment: Still have nothing happening.

Comment: Can you screenshot the game object in the inspector so we can see exactly what components there are :D

Comment: After 4 more revisions of the script, I have identified a new issue:
Unity won't load the script because of nonexistent errors

Comment: Post some screenshots my guy so we can help you better :D